# How to make the "Trust this developer" approval seamless for sideloading from Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I was trying out sideloading an app from source using Xcode, and found that it's not as simple as I expected. (I was expecting to only click "OK" a couple of times and get it over with.)

It turns out I have to manually go to the settings menu and find the "device management" section, after which I make the approval of "Trust this developer", and only then I can load the built app on my iPhone. (As described here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204460)

Is there no way to make this process seamless? It doesn't even have to be an official way but even any hacky way is appreciated.

The reason I ask is because I'm trying to distribute my source and let people sideload it easily, and I want to make it as easy as possible. I can understand all other parts but having to manually jump to settings and find the section, etc. feels too complex for ordinary people…

(Update: I realized that I need to clarify what I'm trying to do. Basically I am trying to open source my code, so people can download it, open it in Xcode, and immediately run it on their phone, so solutions like MDM would not be relevant here. I know I can just give people instructions on how to do this, but I'm just trying to be as user-friendly as possible, so that's why I am ok with hacky ways)

Comment: Probably the simplest approach is just to distribute the app via the App Store for free. You can, of course, continue to make the source code available for those who want to compile it and install it themselves. They can then use their own developer credentials to install the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what your target market is in your question, but as described on the site you linked to, you can use an MDM (mobile device management) solution to distribute your app to people whose devices you have managed by said solution:

> Apple recommends using an (MDM) solution to distribute the apps because it is secure and requires no user interaction. Users can also install these custom apps from a secure website operated by their organization.

Apple provides such a solution with their own [OS X Server](http://www.apple.com/osx/server/) product.

An additional solution (also mentioned on the above site) that may work (though it's been a while since I've done it) is to use an [app manifest file](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW17) to distribute your application on a secure (read: HTTPS-enabled) website that you host.

---

It's worth noting that if you're distributing this to the public at large, rather than employees at your company, beta testers, or similar, you're likely in violation of either the [Apple Developer Program License Agreement](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Documentation/License_Agreements__Apple_Developer_Program/Apple_Developer_Program_Agreement_20160610.pdf) or [Apple Developer Enterprise Program License Agreement](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Documentation/License_Agreements__Apple_Developer_Enterprise_Program/Apple_Developer_Program_Enterprise_Agreement_20160610.pdf), depending on which program you're a part of.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry about the confusion. I've updated the question with more details. Basically I'm trying to do this for an open source project.

Comment: I'm not clear: if the expectation is that they have the source, and they're opening it in Xcode anyway, why wouldn't they just "Build and Run" with their own developer credentials?

Comment: Apple changed their policy with iOS9 where you need to manually go to the settings and approve it https://blog.lookout.com/blog/2015/09/10/ios-9-sideloading More specifically in my case, I am trying to make this easy even for people who don't have a developer account, and by that I mean people who don't have a developer account.

Comment: No, I understood what you meant with the sideloading login, I was referring to building it from source with their own dev account. Since you're wanting to include people who don't have dev credentials, I'm out of ideas. Apple kinda limits this thing on purpose…